# Three20 UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Tags: datasource, three20, cell, uitableview

How do I create an item in my datasource using a cell that is UITableViewCellStyleValue1?  Do I have to create my own custom cell to do it?  I don't see anything in the sample catalog.

thank,
howie

Answer (score 1):

A new table item cell was added that emulates the table settings cell style. see https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/682

You can either merge it manually or wait for the next three20 release which will hopefully include this change.

Answer (score -1):

The point of using UITableViewCellStyleValue1 is that your using a pre-defined layout, so no you don't use a custom layout.

Example:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    cell.textLabel.text = @"SettingLabel";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"SettingValue";

    return cell;
}
```